# Passing RuntimeError to page in production mode

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2, runtime-error, production-environment

Running - for example - a CSV import method can generate errors.

In development mode, Rails will generate a `RuntimeError in UrclassesController#import` with useful information.

This, however, does not get passed in production mode.

Is there a way to capture Rails's RuntimeError and send it to a specific page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For getting notified about exceptions in Production, the [exception_notification](https://github.com/smartinez87/exception_notification) gem may be what you're looking for.  I believe it has handlers for various errors too.